# .NET ランタイムインストールなしに、Windows Vista 以降で実行可能な exe をビルドしたい

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Visual Studio Community 2013 の C# で開発をしています。

Build した exeファイルが下記の環境に標準でインストールされた .Net Framework で(他のバージョンをインストールすること無く)実行されて欲しいのですが、可能でしょうか？

また、その場合に必要な設定を教えていただけるとありがたいです。

対象となる Windows のバージョン

- Windows Vista SP2
- Windows 7 SP1
- Windows 8
- Windows 8.1

32bit / 64bit 版の違いも吸収できるとなお良いです。

Answer (score 3):

- Vista SP2 : .NET 2.0 SP2 + 3.0 SP2
- 7 SP1 : .NET 3.5.1
- 8, 8.1 : .NET 4.5

です。
以上を踏まえると.net 3.0を対象とした上で、[side-by-side ホスティングの一般的なシナリオ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ee518876(v=vs.110).aspx#scenarios)にあるようにアプリケーション構成ファイルを指定すると動作します。

32bit / 64bitの違いについては質問の意図が読み取れませんが、とりあえずAnyCPUを選択するとどちらのbitでも動作するEXEとなります。